# Red wine recipies

Tags: wine, recipe-formulation, red-wine

I'm a new brewer and I want to brew a red wine. Anyone have a good red wine recipie that's easy to make and tastes good? I don't want to buy a kit and I want to use grapes found in the grocery store. I've tried twice to make mead and  it hasn't turned out so I've decided to go to wine

Answer (score 4):

Recipe:
Grape Juice
Yeast

Making wine is more about process than recipe. With the exception of quality ingredients.  Standard table grapes don't really make decent wine.  This becomes incredibly apparent when you actually taste the juice from a true wine grape.  I've dabbled in some wine making all from kits of different grape musts.  When you taste the juice/must from a wine grape it will blow your mind.
What I am saying is that if you want to make wine don't cast off the kits.  The starting material is pretty important.

Comment: *"The starting material is pretty important"*  this is very true.  Unlike beer where you can get decent grains all year, good grapes are hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

I tried once to make a small quantity of wine from grapes I found in a grocery store.  I had big hopes because they got a type of grapes that looked a lot like wine grapes (very dark and small).  Even thought my process was good (already made wine from wine grapes), the end result was not good.
So that means the grapes really need to be wine grapes.  Make an extra effort to find some (web/importation).

An other option is to mix some other fruits.  I once made something very good with raspberries, sugar and vodka.  I fermented the raspberries with sugar, and before the end of fermentation, I added the vodka just to kill the yeast. This gives a fortified wine with just a bit of residual sugar.

Answer (score 1):

My friend has tried this with Concord grapes and it was okay. The recipe he used was on this page: "https://www.baderbrewing.com/content/how-make-wine-concord-table-grapes" Good luck!